# android app crashes while connecting to server socket

Tags: android, multithreading

I am creating a sample bluetooth chat application. While clicking on a available Bluetooth device, I am trying to connect to the device that listens on server socket.

However, In the client thread, when I call `deviceToConnect.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("myuuid"))`
 the application gets crashed.

OnClickListener on ListView

```
 newList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),newDeviceList.get(position).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            ClientThread thread1 = new ClientThread(newDeviceList.get(position));
                            thread1.start();

                        }
                    });
```

Client Thread I am trying to start

```
 public ClientThread(BluetoothDevice deviceToConnect)
    {
        try {
            socket1 = deviceToConnect.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("myuuid"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
           // e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public void run()
    {
         // BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();


    }
```

Though I haven't implemented run method, it seems like the app is crashing when i am calling the thread constructor itself. Where Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Uncomment `e.printStackTrace()`. Post the stack trace.

Comment: Since bluetooth is not supported on the emulator, I am running it on a physical device, and don't know how to print debug info in thread. @EugenPechanec

Comment: On every android device including emulators you can use logcat. Any fatal error will be logged in logcat. `Exception.printStackTrace()` will also be logged in logcat. Use an IDE that allows you to observe logcat easily such as Android Studio.

Comment: I am using android studio. And How can I get logs in actual android device (not emulator) ?

Comment: Enable developer mode and USB Debugging. https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm If you have Huawei or Xiaomi, they're a bit different, Google that.